# Getting error with PubNub PNLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, pubnub

Hi I'm using PubNub api in my project. I'm getting **Implicit declaration of function 'PNLog' is invalid in c99.** I googled about this error, But I can't find solution.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)pubnubClient:(PubNub *)client error:(PNError *)error 
{
    PNLog(PNLogGeneralLevel, self, @"PubNub client report that error occurred: %@", error);
}

- (void)pubnubClient:(PubNub *)client willConnectToOrigin:(NSString *)origin 
{
    PNLog(PNLogGeneralLevel, self, @"PubNub client is about to connect to PubNub origin at: %@", origin);
}

- (void)pubnubClient:(PubNub *)client didConnectToOrigin:(NSString *)origin 
{
    PNLog(PNLogGeneralLevel, self, @"PubNub client successfully connected to PubNub origin at: %@", origin);
}
```

This error is killing my time. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This code already has been replaced in latest client (3.7.9.3) / demo application versions. **PNLog** completely has been removed from client.